# Driver for Realtek PCIE Card Reader S5250?

Tags: drivers, sd-card, realtek

I am running CentOS 7 my MSI Prestige 15 A10SC and the card reader is not working.

It works fine on my dual-boot Windows 10 so I figured I am missing drivers and it seems like so:

```
$ lspci | grep Realtek
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5250 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

However I am unable to find drivers for this particular card reader anywhere. [MSI doesn't even offer Linux drivers on their site](https://www.msi.com/Content-Creation/support/Prestige-15-A10SC). [Nothing on Realtek's site either](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/advanced-search/74?Itemid=276).

Does anyone know of a working/compatible driver or some other workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Googling for this shows that it seems to be used on laptops, e.g. by Dell, and they include the Windows drivers. Your best bet is to reverse-engineer the Windows driver, and write your own. (Or pay someone to do that, or hope that someone with the ability to do that owns the same hardware, needs it, and does it).

Comment: @dirkt well that sucks. I am a developer myself but reverse engineering drivers is way above my league.